# How to share MySQL database connections between users of web app

Tags: java, mysql, web-applications

What would be a good architecture for sharing database connections between users of a web app with Java 7 backend? Currently each user has its own connection to the database and the hundreds of connections is bogging down the system, making it slow.

Comment: Use connection pooling.

Comment: I am assuming this web app is running in some java web application container like tomcat etc. All web application containers have good support for connection pools. Just use them.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!